# looking for Vaadin and Spring archetype

Tags: java, spring, maven, vaadin

I'm starting to develop a new web app application with Vaadin and Spring, but I  can't find an maven archetype for this.

Can you give me some assistance?

Comment: Have you actually tried Maven Central, e.g.: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|vaadin-archetype ?

Comment: i tried maven central but there isn't an archetype that contains both vaadin and spring.

Comment: I'm pretty certain such an archetype does not exists at this very moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such archetype. In fact, just to get those two frameworks working together at all, you're either going to need to go all wild-west and do it yourself (what I did) or use a plugin to get it working.

[Here's the SpringVaadinIntegration plugin.](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/springvaadinintegration). It takes an interesting approach to integrating Spring scopes with Vaadin sessions. The [sample project for that plugin](https://github.com/xpoft/vaadin-samples) will be especially helpful for you to look at.

If you want to do it the do-it-yourself way, I can tell you that I divorced my vaadin from my spring as much as possible. Essentially I created some classes with static references to my spring singleton-scoped beans, and used those static methods for accessing my spring beans from Vaadin.